# How to add conditional ToolbarItems to NavigationView Toolbar with SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

I am trying to add an icon button to the leading edge of a NavigationView's toolbar - but I want that button to only be visible when the device is in landscape mode. (Kinda like how the default Notes app works)

I have the following code:

```
var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // ... content display
        }
        .toolbar {
            if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    Button(action: toggleFullscreen) {
                        if isFullscreen {
                            Image(systemName: "arrow.down.right.and.arrow.up.left")
                        } else {
                            Image(systemName: "arrow.up.left.and.arrow.down.right")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                Button(action: createNewNote) {
                    Image(systemName: "square.and.pencil")
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

If I remove the conditional `if` clause within the toolbar content, it works fine, but it seems to not recognize the `if` statement at all?

However, the `if` statement in the `VStack` works fine.

The specific error I get is:

```
Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with result builder 'ToolbarContentBuilder'
```

Any idea how to fix this?

---

P.S. Consider me a complete SwiftUI noob. Although, I am proficient in React - so any React analogies to help me understand would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're detecting the device orientation in a wrong way `SwiftUI` One way you can achieve that is by using a custom modifier to detect device rotation:

Cfr: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-detect-device-rotation

The code would look like this:

### 1. Create custom modifier: [Detecting Device Rotation](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-detect-device-rotation)

```
// Our custom view modifier to track rotation and call our action
struct DeviceRotationViewModifier: ViewModifier {
    let action: (UIDeviceOrientation) -> Void

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .onAppear()
            .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification)) { _ in
                action(UIDevice.current.orientation)
            }
    }
}

// A View wrapper to make the modifier easier to use
extension View {
    func onRotate(perform action: @escaping (UIDeviceOrientation) -> Void) -> some View {
        self.modifier(DeviceRotationViewModifier(action: action))
    }
}
```

### 2. Use the created modifier:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var isFullscreen = false
    @State private var orientation = UIDeviceOrientation.unknown

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                // ... content display
                
            }
            .onRotate { orientation = $0 }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    if orientation.isLandscape {
                        Button(action: {}) {
                            if isFullscreen {
                                Image(systemName: "arrow.down.right.and.arrow.up.left")
                            } else {
                                Image(systemName: "arrow.up.left.and.arrow.down.right")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button(action: {}) {
                        Image(systemName: "square.and.pencil")
                    }
                }
                
            }
            
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: That works flawlessly. However, I changed the initializer to `private var orientation = UIDevice.current.orientation` - does that make sense?

Comment: Also - I was mainly trying to solve the if statement - and it definitely works when placed within the ToolbarItem's content block - but why doesn't it work in the `toolbar`'s content block like i have in my original code?